# Do I always have to call ->count() before ->first() to prevent "No query results for model [Foo]"?

Tags: php, exception, laravel, eloquent

Do I always have to check for `$this->foo->count()` before I can `$this->foo->first()` to "catch" any `No query results for model [Foo].` "exceptions"?

I've tried this

```
public function hasValid($model)
{   
    try {
        return $this->$model()->firstOrFail()->expiration > date('Y-m-d') ? true : false;
    } catch(ModelNotFoundException $e) {
        return false;
    }
}
```

But I'm still getting `No query results for model [Foo].` when the query returns an empty query set.

I don't always want to prepend any `$this->foo->first()` calls with a  `$this->foo->count()` call just to check for this. There has to be a DRYer solution.

I've got this to be the DRYest so far:

```
public function hasValid($model)
{   
        $model = $this->$model()->first();
        return isset($model) && $model->expiration > date('Y-m-d') ? true : false;
}
```

Comment: Calling `->first()` would've returned you NULL according to Laravel documentation instead of throwing exception. Are you sure you were using `->first()` instead of `->firstOrFail()`. The latter would throw an exception.

Answer (score 1):

You need `use` statement or full namespace for exception:

```
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException;

// or:

catch(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $e)
```

Also you can define default handler, so you can do simply this:

```
public function hasValid($model)
{   
  return ($this->$model()->firstOrFail()->expiration > date('Y-m-d')) ? true : false;
}

// in global.php or wherever, something like this:
App::error(function(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException $exception, $code)
{
    Log::error($exception);

    return Response::make('Not found', 404);
});
```